# Uploading quickly packages to Launchpad

Tags: application-development, ppa, quickly, packaging, launchpad

I created an application using Quickly and packaged it using the command `quickly package`. But after I uploaded it to my PPA, I got a message from Launchpad saying:

> Rejected:
>   Source/binary (i.e. mixed) uploads are not allowed.

How do I solve this problem? Is there any way to tell Quickly not to put binaries in the package?

Answer (score 2):

You can't upload a `.deb` to a PPA, but you can use the command `quickly share` and `quickly release` to create a PPA easily.